# How can I access attributes of a model in admin.TabularInline that is at the end of a manytomany relationship with defined through model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many

I am facing the following scenario;

```
#models.py

class A(models.Model):
    dog = models.CharField(...)
    cat_values = models.ManyToManyField(B, through='AtoB')

class AtoB(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(A)
    two = models.ForeignKey(B)

class B(models.Model):
    cat = models.CharField(...)


#admin.py

class BForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cat = forms.TextInput()

    class Meta:
        model = A.cat_values.through
        exclude = []

class BInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = B.cat_values.through
    form = BForm
    fields = ['cat', ]
    readonly_fields = ['cat', ]

@admin.register(A)
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BInline,]
```

When I try to run server, I get the following error message;

> <class 'agregator.admin.AAdmin.BInline'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[0]' is not a callable, an attribute of 'BInline', or an attribute of 'agregator.AtoB'.

No other forms of access really work like `A.cat_values` or `A.cat_values.two`

I partially understand where is the problem coming from. It does not let me access the B's attributes, only AtoB's attributes. I have tried to work around it but unsuccessfully. Have read the documentation but there is nothing about accessing the attributes in this case scenario, only without a defined through model.

eg https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/

I need to display the `cat` attribute in the inline in the A's admin. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved the issue. The key was to define properties for the `AtoB` model.

For example;

```
class AtoB(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(A)
    two = models.ForeignKey(B)

    @property
    def cat(self):
        return self.two.cat
```